# Referring to a cell/sheet with the variable values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need help accomplishing the following. I don't know any other way to explain this, so here it is:

[image]

**Breakdown:**

1 - A simple dropdown with all months

2 - This is the ID and sheet name for each property

3 - Twelve values (variable), each one corresponds to each month selected from the 1st point: e.g. =IF(D1="JANNUARY","i12".

In C3

I want to have something like: =@INDIRECT(sheetname&valuefromM1)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the problem, exactly?

Comment: What i'm using now is: =@INDIRECT(A119&M1).
In A119 is the name (text) of the sheet name i want to refer to and in M1 (text) is the cell i want to refer to. The A119 part works, but whenever i add the M1, i receive an invalid REF error.

Comment: See how you would normally reference a value from another worksheet, and compare that to what your indirect function does. I bet you are missing an '!' somewhere.

Comment: Also you need to enclose M1 in quotes, otherwise it will insert the value of M1 on the current worksheet.